# Using Arrays in cell formula calc?

Tags: calc

I create Array named *MyArray* from A1:A10!

Ex.1.: How can I get Array[2]'s Value?

Ex.2.: How can I do iterate (for(from 1 to 10)) in cell formula?

Ex.3.: How can I find MyArray value V1, which >=2.4?

I tried write in cell formula `find(MyArray[i],1,10)=2.4`, but it doesn't work!

Please help find answers to these 3 example's questions!

Answer (score 0):

I found [this good solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8zydk03ILXs)
Instead Range for e.g. A1:A10 I can use MyArray;

Ex.1.:

`=INDEX(MyArray;2;1)`

`=INDEX(A1:A10;2;1)`

Ex.2.:  Need to use `=LOOKUP()` function with `=Match()` function

Ex.3.:  Need to use `=LOOKUP()` function with `=Match()` function.